# Bind angular form input fields values from cloud firestore

Tags: angular, firebase

I am using Angular & firebase backend service. I have implemented cloud firestore functinality. I am trying to bind input fields values from database. All works fine but values don't reflect in input fields. If try to console object it returns values correctly but not binding in input fields.

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" #userBusinessForm="ngForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name Of Your Business</label>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="businessData.businessName" formControlName="businessName" name="businessName" class="form-control">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Below method I am calling on ngOnIt which takes reference from service and produce output correctly

```
private getBusinessInfo(){
    this.db.singleBusinessInfo(this.businessID)
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(data =>{
      this.businessData = data;
      this.showSpinner = false;
    }); 
}
```

Only problem is values not getting bind in input fields and also not showing any error in console

Comment: Don't use reactive and template drive form together.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix the two approaches that Angular offers for creating forms:

- [template-driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms), where most of the form-related code is written in the Angular template files (HTML file);
- [reactive](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms), where the logic for the form is inside the component (TypeScript file), and allows you to leverage RxJS observables for easier manipulation.

However, these two don't mix well together, just like a framework's view update algorithm doesn't mix well with jQuery. You're trying to control the same thing from two places, and that ends up in a huge mess under the hood, leading to unexpected behavior which you're facing.

By doing `<form [formGroup]="userForm">`, you chose the reactive approach, but by doing `[(ngModel)]="businessData.businessName"` you switched to the template approach. Check out the `userForm` object which you created (probably with `new FormGroup` or with `this.fb` where `fb` is inejcted `FormBuilder`), and find the name of the field which you want to tie in with the input field on the view. It's probably `businessName`, but I cannot know for sure without seeing enough relevant code (which is why you should've posted a complete minimal reproduction of the issue instead of randomly pasting a chunk of code).

For example, if you have

```
public userForm = this.fb.group({
  businessName: [''],
})
```

then what you need to do is

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  <input formControlName="businessName">
</form>
```

in the template. **Not** the `([ngModel])` thing; that's the template-driven approach.

Comment: This will set blank value in input field. How will I bind object values returned by firebase into input field?

Comment: By using the `setValue` function. I suggest you read more about the forms.